What to name a method which reads and sets value without return value?
I have a method like this
 private void foo() {
    this.myValue = readSomeValueFromFileSystem()
 }

What is the good name for that ? Is there any convention about it ?
I feel that it is kinda set but it doesn't accept anything although classical setter does it.
more context:
Technically this class is a base test class to work with testContainers.
So this class is responsible to start Samba(Active Directory) server. This method is a part of upload test data process. It scans directory for the files with special extensions. So myValue is a list of File Resoures

(Good) method names typically depend on the class name. What does it represent? What is myValue?

This looks a bit like a readConfigFile() method, but without more context we can't be sure.

Added more context to the post. Please take a look.

Just name it after what it does. According to your description, it loads test data. Then call it loadTestData.

@germi It is not loading. Loading is a bigger task and it does method which calls this method.

@gstackoverflow it's still loading something. maybe loadFileResourceList?

You want a name like this to be meaningful within the context it is called. You've showed us the code defining the method, but you haven't showed us how this method is being called. Context matters, especially when naming things.
That being said, the fact this method is private gives more flexibility for the simple reason that nothing outside the current class can call it. Even if it is a bad name, it is a bad name that only exists in one file. Your IDE refactoring tools will make quick work of renaming it.
I would agree that the set moniker doesn't fit this situation. I have a couple of thoughts, one of which veers into the design of this code rather than how the method is named.

When reading from a file system, web service, or database, I like to use the word load followed by one or more words indicating what is being loaded. Here, the word "load" is used as a verb meaning to fill something up. In this case, you are scanning a folder to get a list of files with special extensions: loadFilesWithSpecialExtensions.

Consider the "loading" part to be an implementation detail. Instead of calling this method, which returns nothing, have this method return the file list. The fact it saves the list of file resources in myValue is an implementation detail of the method. Perhaps this is an optimization. This implies downstream changes to callers such that they never access myValue, but instead call this method. Now we have a proper getter:
private Collection<Resource> getFilesWithSpecialExtensions() {
    if (myValue == null) {
        myValue = readSomeValueFromFileSystem();
    }

    return myValue;
}

All other code should call this getter instead of accessing myValue directly. Since you memoize myValue, you won't incur a performance hit calling this method multiple times because you only hit the file system on the first call.



Just call it “setupMyValue”. The caller assumes that myValue has no meaningful contents before the call, but has one after the call. Suitable in situations where the call is synchronous with no possible error. Otherwise the caller doesnt care about how the called function achieves its goal.
